# Detect type of project in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When I create a new project in RStudio, I can choose from among several "types" of projects (e.g., packages, shiny app, blogdown website, etc).

Is there a way to programmatically *detect* what type of project a given R project is?

This would be useful to a workflow package I am developing. If I can detect whether or not a new project is a "package" vs. another kind of project, then I could trigger the addition of certain files that are relevant to packages but not relevant to other project types.

Comment: What are you starting with?  Normally I let RStudio create all those automatic files, then I start coding.  It would have to read my mind to know what kind of project I wanted, because it starts with nothing.

Comment: @user2554330 I'm starting with existing projects. Once a project is created there is stored metadata about the project that indicates its "Project Build Tools". This is chosen in the GUI under Project Options. But I assume there is a way to retrieve this information programmatically.

Comment: I don't think there are published ways to read that, other than reading the rstudio source itself.  It's at github.com/rstudio/rstudio, and since it's not part of the API, would be subject to change without notice.